# python looping through multiline string

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm using a regex search to take out multilines from a text file, and I'm assigning the result in string variable, let's say `x`.

I want to loop through the string line by line same as I can do with an opened text file, but python is looping through each character instead.

Example:

The text file `file.txt` is:

```
ali ali ali
hello world
hello world
ali ali ali
```

And my code:

```
F = open(file.txt, 'r')

x = F.read()
y = re.search(r'ali.[\s\w+].', x, re.DOTALL)    

for line in y:
    print(line)
```

Comment: How this question has been upvoted is mind boggling,  it makes absolutely no sense

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this myself. The answer is :

You need to change `next()` function of `__iter__` method , this could be changed by this line `lineiterator = iter(y.splitlines())`:

```
x = F.read()
y = re.search(r'ali.[\s\w+].', x, re.DOTALL)

lineiterator = iter(y.splitlines())

for line in lineiterator:
    print(line)
```

Comment: So however, here's what I thought: Your answer is code only, and looks doesn't work. So I thought this is what you have tried but doesn't work, if it is then you should edit your question instead of post it an answer. **But if this really is an answer, then post it as an answer is correct**. But remember, don't post a code-only answer, for others it's unclear to understand what's wrong and how to solve it. So please explain that. Anyway, sorry for what I thought.

Comment: thanks for comments , will correct that .

Comment: Ah, that's fine. Now let's talk about your answer: 1. `y = re.search(r'ali.[\s\w+].', x, re.DOTALL)` return a `<class '_sre.SRE_Match'>` object. Also there's no `.splitlines()` method in `_sre.SRE_Match'` object. Do you mean `for line in x.splitlines():`, and `print(re.search(r'ali.[\s\w+].', line, re.DOTALL))` or something like that? 2. Since `str.splitlines()` return a list, `iter()` is useless here. 3. I still little not understand your question, what do you want to get?

Comment: If I try to execute your code, I get `Traceback (most recent call last):||  File "ali.py", line 7, in <module>||    lineiterator = iter(y.splitlines())||   AttributeError: '_sre.SRE_Match' object has no attribute 'splitlines'` (I've put `||` for newlines, that are not allowed in comments). Further, I don't know what you intended your RE to match, but it matched `"ali al"`, is this what you had in mind?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `splitlines` you could use the `readlines` method at once.
Try this

```
F = open('file.txt','r')
x = F.readlines() 
for line in x:
    print line
```

Comment: You don't need the `.readlines()` method, `for line in F: print line` will do perfectly...

Comment: Thanks @gboffi! Thank you for the guidance! will use it nextime!